# how can i stop mediaPlayer in another activity?

Tags: android, media-player

hei, can you help me?, i have 2 activity and i want to stop mediaPlayer in another activity, how to use the button in first activity to stop media player in the second activity, 
my code in  first activity

```
public class homenor extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homenor);

    Button btmateri = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btmateri);


    btmateri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(homenor.this, home.class);
            home.mediaPlayer.stop();
            home.mediaPlayer2.stop();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

and this code in second activity

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {


int [] sound, soalkuis;
int soundke = 0;
int getNosoal = 0;
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, mediaPlayer2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    sound = new int[] {R.raw.definisiprisma1, R.raw.definisiprisma2, R.raw.definisiprisma3,R.raw.jaringprisma1,R.raw.luasprisma1, R.raw.luasprisma2
            ,R.raw.luasprisma3,R.raw.luasprisma4,R.raw.luasprisma5,R.raw.luasprisma6,R.raw.contohluasprisma1,R.raw.penyelesaianluasprisma1,R.raw.contohluasprisma2
            ,R.raw.penyelesaianluasprisma2,R.raw.contohluasprisma3, R.raw.penyelesaianluasprisma3, R.raw.volumeprisma1, R.raw.contohvolume1
            , R.raw.penyelesaianvolumeprisma1, R.raw.contohvolume2, R.raw.penyelesaianvolumeprisma2, R.raw.contohvolume3, R.raw.penyelesaianvolumeprisma3
            , R.raw.rangkumanprisma1, R.raw.rangkumanprisma2};

    soalkuis = new int[] {R.raw.soalprisma1, R.raw.soalprisma2, R.raw.soalprisma3, R.raw.soalprisma4, R.raw.soalprisma5, R.raw.soalprisma6
            , R.raw.soalprisma7, R.raw.soalprisma8, R.raw.soalprisma9, R.raw.soalprisma10};

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(home.this, sound[soundke]);
    mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(home.this, soalkuis[getNosoal]);
    mediaPlayer2.setLooping(false);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

when i try that, i got error like this`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference`
how can i fix that? thank you

Comment: what is your activity flow?
home -> homenor -> home? or homenor -> home?

Comment: homenor -> home

Comment: as per your comment, home activity is not created yet, so it throws null pointer

Answer (score 2):

create class MyMediaPlayer,

```
public class MyMediaPlayer {

private static MyMediaPlayer Instance;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

static MyMediaPlayer getMediaPlayerInstance() {
    if (Instance == null) {
        return Instance = new MyMediaPlayer();
    }
    return Instance;
}

public void playAudioFile(Context context, int sampleAudio) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, sampleAudio);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });

}

public void stopAudioFile() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}}
```

Now, Call this method to play audio

```
MyMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayerInstance().playAudioFile(this, R.raw.sampleaudio)
```

To Stop Audio, Call this method

```
MyMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayerInstance().stopAudioFile()
```

Comment: if it's works then you can mark this as answer, so it will also helps to other people same as upvote

Answer (score 0):

Take the media player as public which you are already taking, then from the second activity, stop the media player like this

```
   try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, can you be clearer specifically?

Comment: Your Media player is public means accessible to other class

Comment: Just call the above code from where you want to stop the media player.  It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to create a class like MediaPlayerManager or ...
create MediaPlayer instance inner this class and implement your interface with your method like pause, play, stop, ...
so, when need action MediaPlayer get instance this class and call suitable method